# Can't setState in react handleClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am unable to `setState` in `handleClick` function for this `App.`
App is working very simple, it has a `data` that has an entry point in `forest` from there it just goes thru `props` till it gets to `Tree` component where divides to `Children` and `Datum` there it has a `Collapsible` that takes care of the expanding logic.

Now,
I just want to mutate `state` I have done many copies of that state with `JSON.parse(JSON.Stringify()))` used `Lodash` for deep copy, everything works expect that `copied and mutated state` just doesn't want to set into `setState` so I can't get it to circular working.
I just want to have a unidirectional data flow, but the 'setState' just doesn't work.

The function that mutates the state `mutateState` takes as arguments a `forest` a `node.id` a `patch or get as a string` value. I have tested it million times and it works, this function mutates the state via recursion. One thing maybe it has a problem that it doesn't `return` anything, even if it doesn't return it still doesn't want to set that 'setState'.

I have also used `debugger` million times and didn't find any clue. Please I need some help.

thank you.

```
import "./App.css";
import { useState, useEffect, useContext, createContext } from "react";
import React from "react";
import data from "./data.json";

import _ from "lodash";
function App() {

  const [state, setState] = useState(data.data);
 
  function mutateState(forest, nodeId, getOrPatch) {
    let result;
    forest.forEach(function (tree) {
      if (tree.id === nodeId && getOrPatch === "patch") {
        tree.toggle === true ? (tree.toggle = false) : (tree.toggle = true);
      } else if (tree.id === nodeId && getOrPatch === "get") {
        return (result = tree.toggle);
      }
      helper(tree);
    });
    function helper(tree) {
      if (tree.children !== null) {
        tree.children.forEach(function (tree) {
          if (tree.id === nodeId && getOrPatch === "patch") {
            tree.toggle === true ? (tree.toggle = false) : (tree.toggle = true);
          } else if (tree.id === nodeId && getOrPatch === "get") {
            return (result = tree.toggle);
          }
          helper(tree);
        });
      }
    }
    return result;
  }

  function Forest({ root }) {
    return root.map((tree) => <Tree root={tree} key={tree.id} />);
  }

  function Tree({ root }) {
    if (root.children !== null) {
      return <Children key={root.id} node={root} />;
    } else {
      return <Datum key={root.id} node={root} />;
    }
  }

  function Collapsible(props) {
    return (
      <ul>
        <button onClick={props.handleClick} className="btn">
          <li>{props.datum}</li>
        </button>
        {props.isExpanded ? props.children : ""}
      </ul>
    );
  }
  
  function Children({ node }) {
    const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = useState(false);
    let stateCopy = _.cloneDeep(state)


    function handleClick() {
      mutateState(stateCopy, node.id,'patch')
      setState(stateCopy)
    
      isExpanded ? setIsExpanded(false) : setIsExpanded(true);
    

    }

    return (
      <Collapsible
        datum={node.datum}
        handleClick={handleClick}
        isExpanded={isExpanded}
      >
        {node.children.map((tree) => (
          <Tree key={tree.id} root={tree} />
        ))}
      </Collapsible>
    );
  }

  function Datum({ node }) {
    return <li>{node.datum}</li>;
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <Forest root={state} />
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

`data JSON`

```
{
    "data": [
        {   
            "datum": "String",
            "id": 1,
            "toggle": false,
            "children": [
                {
                    "datum": "String",
                    "id": 2,
                    "toggle": false,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "datum": "String",
                            "id": 3,
                            "toggle": false,
                            "children": []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "datum": "String",
                    "id": 4,
                    "toggle": false,
                    "children": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "datum": "String",
            "id": 5,
            "toggle": false,
            "children": [{
                "datum": "String",
                "id": 6,
                "children": []
            }]
        },
        {
            "datum": "String",
            "id": 7,
            "toggle": false,
            "children": [
                {
                    "datum": "String",
                    "id": 8,
                    "toggle": false,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "datum": "String",
                            "id": 9,
                            "toggle": false,
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "datum": "String",
                                    "id": 10,
                                    "toggle": false,
                                    "children": [
                                        {
                                            "datum": "String",
                                            "id": 11,
                                            "toggle": false,
                                            "children": []
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "datum": "String",
                            "id": 12,
                            "toggle": false,
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "datum": "String",
                                    "id": 13,
                                    "toggle": false,
                                    "children": []
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "datum": "String",
                    "id": 14,
                    "toggle": false,
                    "children": []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: your mutateState returns a value, you need to use `const results = mutateState(....)`

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial it doesn't return anything it uses `forEach` but besides that, if i just deep copy the array with `lodash` it just won't set that new array to `setState` something is wrong, i don't understand yet what...